# One-way WCF call using netTcpBinding: add OneWayBindingElement through configuration

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding, isoneway

I want to implement a one-way, fire-and-forget call from an ASP.NET application to a WCF service (hosted in a Windows Service). It's a long-running operation at the service-side (otherwise I would just do it inside the ASP.NET application) so the client (channel) should *not* remain open until the action completes.

However trivial a scenario this may seem, I've been searching for a graceful solution for hours and can't really find anything to my liking. There are a couple of SO questions and blog posts about it, and it seems there are two possible solutions:

1. Use a message queue as communication layer, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13929126/1364650).
2. Use `OneWayBindingElement`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244955/1364650).

I would rather not use Message Queues, installing these on the server environment is too much overhead.

That leaves adding `OneWayBindingElement`. But all examples I found do this in code, which I would rather not do because that rules out using the Visual Studio WcfSvcHost. Is it possible to extend my netTcpBinding with this infamous `OneWayBindingElement` through configuration ?

For completeness, here are the key parts in my code:

**Service Interfce**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculationService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void StartTask(TaskType type);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void AbortTask(TaskType type);
}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class CalculationService : ICalculationService
{
    // ...

    public void StartTask(TaskType type)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Client code, inside controller**

```
public class SourcesController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(UploadFilesVM files)
    {
        // ...

        using(var svcClient = GetSvcClientInstance())
        {
            svcClient.StartTask(TaskType.RefreshInspectionLotData);
            svcClient.StartTask(TaskType.RefreshManugisticsData);
        }

        // ...

        return RedirectToAction("Progress");
    }

    private CalculationServiceClient GetSvcClientInstance()
    {
        var client = new CalculationServiceClient();
        client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new SatBehavior(Context));
        client.Open();
        return client;
    }
}
```

**Service configuration**

```
<services>
    <service name="...CalculationService">
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/PLU0006B/"/>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8733/PLU0006B/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint 
            address="CalculationService" 
            binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="SatOneWayBinding" 
            contract="....ICalculationService" />
        <endpoint 
            address="mex" 
            binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>

<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="SatOneWayBinding">
            <!-- I'm hoping I can configure 'OneWayBindingElement' here ? -->
            <security mode="None">
            </security>
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: "But all examples I found do this in code, which I would rather not do because that rules out using the Visual Studio WcfSvcHost." .. how does that rule out using WcfSvcHost ?
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)] is enough to make calls to this operation work in a "fire-and-forget" behaviour

Comment: @SirajMansour: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be that easy. Although the code does immediately 'return' after making the call, and thus *appears* to be one-way, WCF does keep the channel open for as long as the operation lasts service-side. And therefore the ASP.NET session with it. Trying to 'forcefully' `Close` the client *will* halt execution, until a timeout exception is thrown.